# AngularJS: Link function does not get evaluated attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I expect that function `step` will be evaluated and its result will be passed right to the `link` function. But, when `link` function get called it has nothing in `$scope.name` variable. `$args.checkStep` is empty also. Is is by design?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>angularjs link function doesn not get evaluated paramter</title>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <custom-include src="inc/homepage.html" prefix="homepage" suffix="" tag="release"></custom-include>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('customInclude', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                type: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
                var prefix = $attr.prefix || '',
                    suffix = $attr.suffix || '';
                $scope.step = function (s) {
                    console.log('step', prefix, s, suffix);
                    return prefix + s + suffix;
                };
            },
            template: function (elem, attr) {
                return `
<h2>Fusce lorem ante</h2>
<ul>
    <li check-step="{{step(1)}}">Vestibulum efficitur</li>
    <li check-step="{{step(2)}}">Arcu vitae iaculis sodales</li>
    <li check-step="{{step(3)}}">Ligula ex interdum neque</li>
    <li check-step="{{step(4)}}">Ac iaculis felis lectus in purus.</li>
</ul>
`;
            }
        };
    });

    app.directive('checkStep', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                name: '@checkStep'
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
                console.log('link', $scope.name);
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

---- Update ----

Why did the following code works:

```
<li check-step="{{1+step(1)}}">Vestibulum efficitur</li>
```

But this doesn'nt:

```
<li check-step="{{step(1)}}">Vestibulum efficitur</li>
```

?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mateyahowo/edit?js,console)
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CHfGfeynGcVsF9Qhtlv9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute value is computed and put on the isolate scope after invocation of the link function. Use a `$watch` to see the eventual value:

```
app.directive('checkStep', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            name: '@checkStep'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
            //console.log('link', $scope.name);
            //use $watch
            $scope.$watch("name", function(newValue) {
                console.log('link', newValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/pMFi9jP9spVBDuPrQ4Qd?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It wont' work because `link` of an inner component get called **always before** of a `link` function of an outer component. The right place for exposing API for descendants is `controller`.

The question

> Why did the following code works:

```
<li check-step="{{1+step(1)}}">Vestibulum efficitur</li>
```

is incorrect. This is not working, at least as expected. When AngularJS evaluates `1+step(1)` it yields just `1` instead of `1 + <result of step(1)>`. This is due to the fact that `step` function is not defined yet! Although *isolated* or *inherited* scope might be created (if it was specified).

Here is what happened:

1. Create a scope for `custom-include`. An isolated one with `type` field will be created, as it was specified in [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) (`{scope: {type: '@'}}`).
2. Call `custom-include.controller`. This is the time where you can add some API for children components. But it was not specified in [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), so it won't be called.
3. Create a scope for `check-step`. An isolated one with `name` field will be created, as it was specified in [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) (`{scope: {name: '@checkStep'}}`).
4. Call `check-step.controller`. Again, since it was not specified in [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), nothing will be called.
5. Call `check-step.link`. This time you can add some *event listeners*.
6. Call `custom-include.link`.

**The solution** is to move `$scope.step = function (s) {...}` into `controller`. That way, when `check-step.link` function will be called, `step` function will be defined in parent scope and will be called. The drawback of this methods is that when `check-step.name` get changed, `check-step.link` wont be notified about it.

```
app.directive('customInclude', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
            var prefix = $attrs.prefix || '',
                suffix = $attrs.suffix || '';
            $scope.step = function (s) {
                console.log('step', prefix, s, suffix);
                return prefix + s + suffix;
            };
        }],
```

...

To summarize:

1. A scope get created.
2. A controller get called.
3. Any expressions get evaluated (context is a scope just created).
4. If there are any descendants they will be initialized the same way.
5. A link function get called.